# On a certain integral with trigonometric substitution not allowed

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I got a question. It says find a step by step algorithm to compute the antiderivative of $$\int \frac{P(x) } {(1+x^2)^n} $$. 
Where P(x)  is a polynomial and partial fraction  could be used while trigonometric substitution should not be used.

Comment: Algorithm: Long Division over and over again, and then partial fractions once you must. The partial fractions won't be pretty, but are going to be exact if I am not mistaken because we have a quadratic.

Comment: What more do you want? This process is guaranteed to work already.